# Getting persistent error when trying to predict new data from a GLM in R

Tags: r, dataframe, glm, predict, gamma

I'm getting a persistent error "Error: variables ‘x1’, ‘x2’, ‘x3’ were specified with different types from the fit" while trying to predict the outcome of new data using predict in R. I've run this code with success on other models, but for some reason I can't figure out what is wrong with this one. I've replicated the issue with the following code:

```
# make data
set.seed(19870630)
n <- 1000
df <- data.frame(y = rgamma(n, shape = .5, rate = 1),
                 #runif(n, 0, 1), # trows same error
                 x1 = runif(n, 0, 100),
                 x2 = runif(n, 0, 100),
                 x3 = runif(n, -1, 1))

df$x2 <-  df$x1*df$x1

# refine data by scaling
df$x1 <- scale(df$x1, center = TRUE)
df$x2 <- scale(df$x2, center = TRUE)
df$x3 <- scale(df$x3, center = TRUE)

# double check
head(df); plot(df)

# fit model
mod <- glm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, data = df, family=Gamma(link="log"))

# confirm, success
summary(mod)


# make data to retain predictions
## first get realistic ranges of variables of interest, other vars will be held at mean
(x1_span <- c(rep(seq(min(df$x1), max(df$x1)), length = 50)))
(x2_span <- c(rep(seq(min(df$x2), max(df$x2)), length = 50)))


df_pred_x1_x2 <- data.frame(x1 = x1_span,
                            x2 = x2_span,
                            x3 = mean(df$x3))

# generate function for prediction ml predicted values
predict_fun <- function(my_glm) {
  predict(my_glm, newdata = df_pred_x1_x2)   # this is predict.glm
}

df_pred_x1_x2$y_value_pred <- predict_fun(mod) # error

# "Error: variables ‘x1’, ‘x2’, ‘x3’ were specified with different types from the fit"
                                                      
# End March 8, 2021
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `scale()` makes the variables into single-column matrices (note the `num [1:1000, 1]`) in the description of `x1` below.  To be honest, I'm never sure when this is or isn't going to cause trouble ...

```r
str(df)
'data.frame':   1000 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ y : num  ...
 $ x1: num [1:1000, 1] 1.448 -1.702 -0.559 -1.147 0.732 ...
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:center")= num 49.2
  ..- attr(*, "scaled:scale")= num 28.5
...
```

You can work around this by calling `df <- lapply(df,drop)` to drop the extra dimension (*before* you fit the model).  @dlaggy points out that you can also define your own scaling function (`function(x) (x-mean(x))/sd(x)`); you could also define

```r
myscale <- function(...) drop(scale(...))
```

Note that unlike using `c()` (which I had suggested in my previous answer), which drops dimensions *and* other attributes, `drop()` only drops dimensions - so you can keep your scale/center attributes with the data as you go along.

Comment: This looks great, but I think the problem is not the attributes, but rather that `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` are matrices/arrays while the new input is a numeric. Creating a new centering function such as this is another approach: `function(x) (x - mean(x)) / sd(x)`

Comment: Thank you both, very helpful workarounds, I was able to get the predict to work. In the case of my analysis, I did want to keep those attributes around somewhere to transform the variables back for plotting. I just saved the center and scale attributes into their own objects before using `df <- apply(df,drop)`.